# Parsing JSON response using PHP for Yelp API

Tags: php, json, api, parsing, yelp

I can't seem to parse information sent by the Yelp API. Here's the output: http://www.coroomer.com/apartments/yelp.php.

Here is the segment of the code I am having trouble with:

```
// Send Yelp API Call
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $signed_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Handle Yelp response data
$obj = json_decode($response,true);

// Print it for debugging
//print_r($obj);

echo var_dump($obj);

if (isset($bus)) {
foreach($obj[businesses] as $bus){
    echo $bus[name];
    echo $bus[reviews];
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't get a correctly "formatted" output. Formatted as in it looks like the review threads on Yelp. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The output in the link you provided is not JSON. Looks like output from PHP's `var_dump()`

Comment: What's your problem man!?it's not clear what you want to reach.

Comment: show us the link to "review thread on Yelp", so we can know what are you trying to do

Comment: sorry guys, im still new to this. that IS the output from var_dump, i'm trying to parse it so that it looks something like this: http://www.allmenus.com/ca/san-francisco/276369-boogaloos/reviews/

specifically, the problem im having is that the foreach loop isnt firing. its supposed to retrieve the correctly formatted response from yelp.

Comment: been trying to echo reviews but the output is "array". heres what i got so far: http://www.coroomer.com/apartments/yelp.php.

anyone how to output the text for the reviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly you are asking. However...

1. Fix your warnings and notices first. Do not try to access arrays without single or double quotes around indexes, because PHP will try to resolve them as CONSTANTS. Which will lead to:

a. Slower runtime

b. Headaches, if a constant exists with that index

Change this code:

```
foreach($obj[businesses] as $bus){
    echo $bus[name];
    echo $bus[reviews];
```

to

```
foreach($obj['businesses'] as $bus){
    echo $bus['name'];
    echo $bus['reviews'];
```

2. The dump doesn't have any array with the index `businesses`, what are you trying to iterate over here?

Comment: not sure if im understanding this, going off of this: http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/search_api

yelp puts all information under "businesses". inside the foreach loop, i'm trying to echo different pieces of information from that business which I had linked to but it isnt shown above. the foreach loop isnt firing, i am totally lost as to why. i'll remove isset so show u the error messages i am getting

Comment: @ejunprung: You should do a `business_review_search` request to `http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search`, in order to get all the business, so you can iterate over them. The type of the request you are making at the moment seems to be [this one](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/business).

Comment: @shef thanks for much for the help. i think i understand the problem. i would like to use yelp api v2. here's the output i am trying to get: allmenus.com/ca/san-francisco/276369-boogaloos/reviews.

i sent a request to http://api.yelp.com/v2/business/{business id here}

i think the problem is this: 
foreach($obj['businesses'] as $bus){
    echo $bus['name'];
    echo $bus['reviews'];
}

"businesses" is not a valid index. from yelp's api documentation, do you know what i should be putting there instead? i am totally lost and have been searching everywhere for a solution.

Comment: i figured it out, thanks! i'm stupid, i shouldnt be using foreach as i am requesting information for only one business.